How to add new elements to a container so that they are indented from each other
I'm weak in the frontend, so I don't understand what I'm doing wrong, I'm creating a div and inside this div I'm creating span and a, then I add that div to notificationContainer but they are layered over each other, I want them to be stacked on top of each other.
I tried to do a lot of things, but nothing seemed to work.
Screenshot from the inspector
CSS
.notification-block {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: #007bff;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  z-index: 1000;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-top: 10px; /* Add margin between notifications */
}
.notification-block a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
.notification-block .close-btn {
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  cursor: pointer;
}

Javascript
socketNotif.onmessage = function (event) {
  const data = JSON.parse(event.data);
  console.log("Notification received:", data);
  showNotification(data);
};
function showNotification(message) {
  const notificationContainer = document.getElementById("notificationContainer");
  const notificationElement = document.createElement("div");
  notificationElement.className = "notification-block";

  const aLink = document.createElement("a");
  aLink.setAttribute("href", `/chat/${message.chat_id}`);
  aLink.textContent = message.message;

  const spanMessage = document.createElement("span");
  spanMessage.className = "close-btn";
  spanMessage.innerHTML = "&times;";

  spanMessage.addEventListener("click", function () {
    notificationContainer.removeChild(notificationElement);
  });

  notificationElement.appendChild(aLink);
  notificationElement.appendChild(spanMessage);
  notificationContainer.appendChild(notificationElement);
}

document.getElementById("notificationLink").addEventListener("click", function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  window.location.href = "/chat"; // Adjust the URL as needed
});


All your notification elements (those with thenotification-block class), have the position set to fixed so with the same left and bottom values. Due to that they are all placed on the same position.
You instead want to set fixed position on the element with the id notificationContainer


#notificationContainer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 20px;
  left: 20px;
}

.notification-block {
  width: 300px;
  background-color: #007bff;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  z-index: 1000;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-top: 10px;
  /* Add margin between notifications */
}

.notification-block a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.notification-block .close-btn {
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  cursor: pointer;
}
<div id="notificationContainer">
  <div class="notification-block">
  </div>
  <div class="notification-block">
  </div>
  <div class="notification-block">
  </div>
</div>



